# Casting interface pointers with user-defined conversion operators

Tags: c#, .net

I have created an interface, that two different classes implement in C#. I have also implemented a user-defined conversion operator between the two classes. It is however not always called when interface pointers are used. I'm wondering why it's not, and if there's a way to make it so?

This is my code:

```
namespace InvalidCastReproducer
{
    class Program
    { 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyType1 type1 = new MyType1();
            MyType2 type2;
            IMyType itype1 = new MyType1();
            IMyType itype2;

            type2 = (MyType2)type1;
            itype2 = (MyType2)type1;

            try
            {
                type2 = (MyType2)itype1;
            }
            catch (InvalidCastException iex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(iex.Message);
            }

            try
            {
                itype2 = (MyType2)itype1;
            }
            catch (InvalidCastException iex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(iex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    public interface IMyType {}
    public class MyType1 : IMyType {}
    public class MyType2 : IMyType
    {
        public static explicit operator MyType2(MyType1 type1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("User-defined conversion operator called.");
            return new MyType2();
        }
    }
}
```

I would have expected the user-defined conversion operator to be called all four times, but it is not. This is my output:

```
User-defined conversion operator called.
User-defined conversion operator called.
Unable to cast object of type 'InvalidCastReproducer.MyType1' to type 'InvalidCastReproducer.MyType2'.
Unable to cast object of type 'InvalidCastReproducer.MyType1' to type 'InvalidCastReproducer.MyType2'.
```

So it seems like when the type to cast *from* is a pointer of the interface type, it doesn't find the conversion operator, even if the instance is of the correct type.

I was considering implementing a conversion operator from `IMyType` to `MyType2`, but that isn't allowed by the compiler.

Comment: Your operator works on your MyType2 class. If you have an interface, you can't use it. You can do type2 = (MyType2)(MyType1)itype1; if you know that interface is of class MyType1 but I personally prefer other ways (copy contructor, CopyTo method...) that works directly with the interface.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, explicit operators from interfaces or base types are not allowed in C#.

Basing on your code, you're converting rather than casting. You can achieve what you want using eg. contructor:

```
public class MyType2 : IMyType
{
    public MyType2()
    {
    }

    public MyType2(IMyType itype)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend creating a pattern matching factory

```
public class MyType2 : IMyType
{
    public static explicit operator MyType2(MyType1 type1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("User-defined conversion operator called.");
        return new MyType2();
    }

    public static MyType2 FromMyType(IMyType value)
    {
        if (value is MyType2 t2) return t2;
        if (value is MyType1 t1) return (MyType2)t1;
        throw new ArgumentException($"Cannot convert from {value.GetType().Name}");
    }
```

to be called from the remaining program instead of a conversion

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IMyType im1 = new MyType1();
        IMyType im2 = new MyType2();

        var m2_1 = MyType2.FromMyType(im1);
        var m2_2 = MyType2.FromMyType(im2);
    }
```